# How to add permission for cron jobs in cpanel

Tags: cron, cpanel, permission-denied

I am trying top set cron job using cpanel interface.

But am getting response mail as "permission denied"

How can i set permission for cron job to a user in cpanel ?

Comment: I imagine corn jobs are seasonal

Comment: they should be delicious, i also want corn jobsss :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your account may not have enough permission for crons, talk to your hosting and ask them to:

go to /var/adm/cron directory.
cat the contents of cron.allow and check if user name u are using is there or not.
if not add the username .